# How can I create multiple hillshade maps using a for loop that searches a table?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcpy

```
 import arcpy.sa

 arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\nhaddad\Desktop\project_8"

 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

 altitude_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("solar_points", "Altitude")

 azimuth_cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("solar_points", "Azimuth")

 for i,j in zip(altitude_cursor,azimuth_cursor):

       output = arcpy.sa.Hillshade(r"C:\Users\nhaddad\Desktop\final_exam\worcester_dem", j[0], i[0], "SHADOWS", 0.348)
```

I can only create 1 output map, when I need the loop to iterate through the 10 rows of the table and make 10 maps.

Comment: Have a look at the code samples here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/hillshade.htm

Answer (score 0):

You never save your hillshade or add it to a list (or other data structure) to use the results later. You can save the hillshade result by simply using [`output.save("/path/to/destination/file/name")`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/hillshade.htm).

Something else, please use `with` when working with `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` to ensure that the cursor is closed again after you don't need it anymore. Furthermore, you don't need two cursors.

```py
import os
import arcpy, arcpy.sa

DEM = r"C:\Input\Hillshade\worcester_dem"
SOLAR_POINTS_FOLDER = r"C:\Input\SolarPoints"

OUTPUT_FOLDER = r"C:\Output"

with arcpy.EnvManager(workspace=SOLAR_POINTS_FOLDER):

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("solar_points", ["Azimuth", "Altitude"]) as cursor:
        
        for azimuth, altitude in cursor:
            
            output = arcpy.sa.Hillshade(DEM, azimuth, altitude, "SHADOWS", 0.348)
            
            # either save file (or add it to an array for later use)
            output.save( \
                os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, f"worcester_{azimuth}_{altitude}"))
```

**Note:** Above example is written from memory without being tested/executed.

Answer (score 0):

It took 26 minutes to run the code but here's what I came up with based on Thomas' answer:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#set workspace and output overwrite
arcpy.env.workspace = (r"Z:\personal\comp_forgis23\Lab7_Raster")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
inRaster="worcester_dem" #raster input
outFolder= (r"Z:\personal\comp_forgis23\Lab7_Raster")
shadows='SHADOWS'#model shadows for display
zfactor=0.348
#use a new search cursor that looks at each row, only includes azimuth and altitude
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('solarangle',['azimuth','altitude']) as cursor:
    for azimuth, altitude in cursor:
        hillOutput = Hillshade(inRaster, azimuth, altitude, shadows, zfactor)
        hillOutput.save(f'Z:\personal\comp_forgis23\Lab7_Raster\woo_{azimuth}_{altitude}.tif')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).